# Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException in Slim 4.7

Tags: php, backend, slim

Im trying to launch my app , but everytime i open in my browser `http://localhost/` it gives me this error :

```
/* namespace handles; use connection\Sql; use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response; use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request; use Slim\Factory\AppFactory; $app = AppFactory::create(); $sql = new Sql(); $stmt = $sql -> comand( "SELECT * FROM substancias" ); $app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) { $name = $args['name']; $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name"); return $response; }); $app->run(); var_dump($stmt); */

Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found. in C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:91 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(72): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) 
#1 C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) 
#2 C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(215): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) 
#3 C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(199): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) 
#4 C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\src\index.php(24): Slim\App->run() 
#5 {main} thrown in C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php on line 91
```

I already tried to `setBasePath` ,but still not works , can someone helps ? thanks

Index.php code inside `C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\src`  :

```
<?php
namespace src;

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
require("../autoload.php");

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use handles\userhandle;

$ei = "test";

$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->setBasePath('/myapp');

$user = new userhandle();

$app->get('/aki' , function(Request $request, Response $response){
    global $user;
    $user->VER($request, $response);
});

$app->run();

var_dump($ei);

?>
```

userhandle.php inside `C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\vendor\src\handles` :

```
<?php
namespace handles;

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
require("../../../vendor/autoload.php"); 

use connection\Sql;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

class userhandle {
    private $sql;

    public function VER(Request $request, Response $response){
        $this->sql = new sql();
        
        $stmt = $this->sql -> comand(
        "SELECT * FROM substancias"
        );
        $response->getBody()->write($stmt);
        return $response;
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: In the code you've shared you only define one route (at `/aki`). You don't define routes for `/`.

Comment: The `vendor/` directory is only for the composer packages and not for your codebase. The `src/` directory is not a the `src` namespace. The index.php file should be placed in `public/index.php`. [Read more](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html)

Comment: I changed the path of the files , after researh I found a article how to arrange my files with  slim , i changed the index.php to :C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\public , and userhandle.php to : C:\Users\mathe\Desktop\conscious\backend\src\handles . but the problems continues , when I go to localhost the same problem show in screen

Comment: Not sure why I didn't get any feedback but I presume you want to load `http://localhost/myapp/aki` rather than `http://localhost/` (and maybe even with some non-default port, that's impossible to say).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after -> `$app = AppFactory::create();`

add   -> `$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);`

add   -> `$app->setBasePath("/project_folder/api");` //folder where index.php is located

this is my .htaccess (located also api folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Comment: Happy to helped

Comment: Thanks! Fast fix to an annoying install path problem.